# How to get layer from modify event of insertVertexCondition method?

Tags: openlayers

For my dev, I want to get the text of the current selected layer from event of modify interaction.

Below is the code snippet I used, but I can't get text of layer.

```
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features,
    pixelTolerance: 1,
    deleteCondition: event => {
      return false;
    },
    insertVertexCondition: event => {
        const coordinates = event.coordinate;

        const layers = event.target.getLayers().getArray();
        layers.forEach(layer => {
          if (
            layer.getProperties().name === 'section-layer' &&
            layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPoint'
          ) {
            const layerSource = layer.getSource();

            const layerText = layer.pleaseHelp(); // Please help with this method.

            const calibrationPoint = new ol.Feature({
              geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinates),
              text: 'calibration',
              layer: layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getProperties().text
            })
            layerSource.addFeatures([calibrationPoint])
          }
        })

        return false;
      }
  });

  map.addInteraction(modify);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about layer property that was assigned to the layer at the time of layer creation

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  text: 'This is some text'
});
```

or later by `set` method

```
layer.set('text', 'Some other text');
```

then you can get this value simply by `get` method:

```
var layerText = layer.get('text');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this method.

Comment: Can I get the selected layer from the event of the insertVertexCondition method?

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, which means one question per question. If you have a new question, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your notice.